# Definiteness of a matrix

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

I have a question about matrices. I have the following symmetric matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 & 0\\ -1 & 1 & -1\\ 0 & -1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

The first leading minor is positive. The second as well, but the third is negative. Is it now the case that this matrix is indefinite?

Thanks for your profound help!

Comment: Yes. In particular, its signature is $(2,1,0)$.

Comment: Thank you mister Sassatelli for the confirmation !